# merging duplicate strings in text

Tags: python, bash

I have a word frequency list in this format:

```
3 yaz
1 yazlik
5 zemin
3 zemine
1 zeminde
2 zeminler
```

`zemine` and `zeminde` are different strings but has same root `zemin`

I want to merge the list like this:

```
4 yaz
11 zemin
```

How can I do that with bash or python?

Comment: What determines the "root" of a word? Would `aggravate` and `apple` have the same root `a`?

Comment: @ZevChonoles good question. actually this process is too hard than i think

Comment: You have to define the root of a word. Workaround would be to check : if 'zemin' in 'zemindler': print "true" But then this would run into issues when abzeminad would also be in a list. Though root is not zemin, but my code would still produce true for the if statement.

Comment: Look up "stemming" (e.g., see Porter's algorithm mplementation in the `nlp` Python package)

Comment: Something like: Sort on second field. Loop through file `while read num word; do` . Remember last word and check the that the lastword is a substring of the new word, Yes: Add num, no echo old sum and old root and store new root end new sum equal to new num.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `bash` (4.0+) that **works even with an unsorted list**:

```
$ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash
declare -A roots # declare roots as an associative array (bash 4.0+)
while read n word; do
    unset shortest longest
    # check if the element (or its root) is already registered
    for root in "${!roots[@]}"; do
        if [[ "$root" =~ ^$word ]]; then
            shortest=$word
            longest=$root
        elif [[ "$word" =~ ^$root ]]; then
            shortest=$root
            longest=$word
        fi
    done
    # if registered, check if it must be replaced for a shorter one (its root)
    if [ "$longest" ] && [ "${roots[$longest]}" ]; then
        tmp_n=${roots["$longest"]}
        unset roots["$longest"]
        roots["$shortest"]=$tmp_n 
    fi
    # register or update the element
    let roots[${shortest:-$word}]+=$n
done < list

# print the result
for root in "${!roots[@]}"; do
    echo "${roots[$root]} $root"
done
```

#### Example

```
$ cat list
3 yaz
1 yazlik
1 zeminde
5 zemin
3 zemine
2 zeminler

$ ./script.sh 
4 yaz
11 zemin
```